# How to access nested union members using SWIG?

Tags: python, c, swig, unions

I have a structure like this in C:

```
struct print_arg {
    struct print_arg        *next;
    enum print_arg_type     type;
    union {
        struct print_arg_atom       atom;
        struct print_arg_field      field;
        struct print_arg_typecast   typecast;
        struct print_arg_flags      flags;
        struct print_arg_symbol     symbol;
        struct print_arg_func       func;
        struct print_arg_string     string;
        struct print_arg_op     op;
        struct print_arg_dynarray   dynarray;
    };
};
```

I am using `swig` to export a `python` bindings. Actually swing doesn't support nested unions like this, but with a variable declaration it is ok :

```
union {
    struct print_arg_atom       atom;
    struct print_arg_field      field;
    ...
} value;
```

This solution actually doesn't fits to me because it breaks lots of C code using this structure (you change the way to access union members).

I think of two possibilities :

1. Add the `value` variable declaration, so the swig problem is resolved but I need a way to access union members directly in C (to not breaking lots of functions). Do you know one or more ?
2. Find an other way in swig. Do you know one or more ?

Any other solution is welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to feed the C code and SWIG two different header files. Try this code:

```
union {
    struct print_arg_atom       atom;
    struct print_arg_field      field;
    ...
} /*SWIG_VALUE*/;
```

When you run SWIG to create the JNI code, replace `/*SWIG_VALUE*/` with `value`. This should not change the addresses of the fields but it will make the structure more accessible to SWIG.